# Mplayer doesn't prevent screensaver in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver, mplayer, xscreensaver

I'm trying to watch a movie using mplayer, and despite putting `stop-xscreensaver=yes` in my `/etc/mplayer/mplayer.conf` file, and also starting mplayer using the `-stop-xscreensaver`, I still have to sit near enough to my PC to move the mouse every 15 mins to stop the screensaver taking over.

Any ideas?

*Linux mythbuntu 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: I believe that newest Ubuntu (with Unity) use different style of screensaver than xscreensaver.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in your home dir in `~/.mplayer/config`